# AWS glue get columns by name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-workflow

I have 2 types of csv files - one containing 10 columns and one containing 50 columns. The 10 columns from the first file type appear also in the second file type and I want to crawl only these 10 columns from both of the file types.
In the future, I might have different file types containing these 10 columns and some additional columns.
How can I get the 10 columns by the column name? The column name will remain the same always.

Comment: I don't think that's supported. You might need to create a table with all 50 columns and then later select only those you care about.

Comment: So I need to create table for each possible file type and then union all tables?

Comment: yup, that seems like the correct approach